# Joomla 3x MVC Component "getState" not working properly

Tags: component, front-end

I'm developing something like a content component I choose a specific item through Menu Items component and choose what item i want so that once i navigate to that menu I can see the item i choose however on the frontend model of my component the desired functionality didn't work instead of getting the **Second Item from the table** it retrieves always the **First Item**. see the sample snippets of my **getData** and **getState**. and btw **$id** value must be 2 and not 1.

Please help me to fix this. Thanks.

```
  public function &getData($id = null) {

    if ($this->_item === null) {
        $this->_item = false;
        if (empty($id)) {
        $id = $this->getState('articlefile.id');
 }
```

Comment: Your question is not that descriptive. I am getting no idea what you want to do after all. Please describe your problem in detail.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the second item i choose using the menu item however on the getData function in my frontend model always return the first row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

**Closed** on my "populateState" function inside my frontend model for a single item. I changed my code to this.

```
  if (isset($params_array['item_id'])) {
        $this->setState('articlefile.id', $id);
        // change $params_array['item_id'] to $id
    }
```

this previous code before changing is to determine if the **item_id** is already set and then it is the one assign to the "articlefile.id" that is why always the first row is being retrieved from the table.